# How to fix webpack loader issue in typscript monorepo

Tags: typescript, webpack, monorepo

I have made a typescript monorepo [here](https://github.com/hali241997/jest-rollup-issue) with the following folder structure:

```
.
└── packages
    ├── package.json // Housing the monorepo workspace
    ├── web-app // Housing the NextJS website
    └── web-core // Housing the redux business logic
```

Whenever I run `yarn dev` inside the root or inside the `web-app`, I get the following parsing error:

```
error - ../web-core/index.ts
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| export * from "./counter";
| export { default as MyProvider } from "./provider";
> export type { RootState } from "./store";
|
```

I know this is some webpack or babel issue insider `web-core` but I would need some guidance as to how can I solve this. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing `type` from `export type { RootState } from "./store";`?

Comment: That would be of no use. More errors are gonna pop up. I need to somehow parse this using some loaders. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to it. I am using a monorepo approach with NextJS in `web-app` and Redux in `web-core`. To consume the `web-core` inside the `web-app`, I need to first build it the `web-core`. Adding it to the `package.json` of `web-app` isn't enough. Since I am not planning to publish `web-core` as a separate npm package, I just need to build it.

To build it, I added the `next-transpile-modules` as a dev dependency to `web-app` and added the code in `next.config.js`:

```
...

const withTM = require("next-transpile-modules")(["@issue/web-core"]);

module.exports = withTM(nextConfig);
```